# Javascript checking if a variable is between 2 values + else

Tags: javascript

I need help with this simple issue. Whenever I activate the code below, I always get the result from else, no matter my input. I want to check if the day is between 1 and 30 inclusive, and if it is activate whatever is inside the if function. If it's not between 1 and 30, I want to run the else function and display the error message.

```
var day;
    function changePage(){
        if(day < 30 && day > 1){
           day = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
           console.log(day);
           window.location.href = "day-" + day + ".html";}
        else{
           alert("Invalid entry, must be between 1 and 30");}}
```

Comment: where do you assign `day` value?

Comment: `day === undefined` so it's not between 1 and 30.

Answer (score 2):

Your day isn't set until you hit the loop. You need to define `day` either outside or within the function but before the loop

```
function changePage() {
    var day = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
    if (day < 30 && day > 1) {
        console.log(day);
        window.location.href = "day-" + day + ".html";
    } else {
        alert("Invalid entry, must be between 1 and 30");
    }
}
```

Comment: DUUUUUH! Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem @Mishapopkin we all make those mistakes ^_^

Answer (score 0):

> I always get the result from else

Yes it's logical because `day` in your code is `undefined` so the following `if` statement `if(day < 30 && day > 1)` will be always `false` so the `else` part will be always reached.

In your deaclartion initialize the `day` variable, like this:

```
var day = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I understand, I defined       day inside my function. I changed it to outside the if else function and it worked. Thank you everyone.